# Can radical extension tower of a non-root of unity over $p$-adic fields be Galois?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  Let $a\in K^\times$ which is not a root of unity.  Then do we have the following?

There exists $N$ such that for $n\geq N$,
 $K(\alpha)/K$ is not Galois for every $\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ satisfies $\alpha^{p^n}=a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT. Rewritten answer after discussion with the OP.

Now that I understand correctly your question, it seems that the solution is merely Galois theoretic. For simplification, suppose that $K$ contains $\mu_p$ and $p\neq 2$. Denote $K_n = K(\mu_{p^n}), G_n=Gal(K_n/K)$. Fix $a\in K^*$, not a $p$-primary root of 1, and define $L_n=K_n(\sqrt [p^n]a), H_n=Gal(L_n /K_n)$ (which is cyclic of order dividing $n$).

Obviously $L_n /K$ is normal iff the extensions of the elements of $G_n$ to automorphisms of a normal closure of $L_n$ stabilize $H_n$, and this action (via inner automorphisms) will define a character $\chi_n : G_n \to H_n$. But, by Kummer theory, $H_n\cong Hom (<a>_n,\mu_{p^n})$, where $<a>_n$ is the subgroup of ${K_n}^*/{{K_n}^*}^{p^n}$ generated by the class of $a$. Recall that the (only) functorial action of $G_n$ on $Hom(.)$ is defined by $(g(f))(x)=g(f(g^{-1}(x))$. It will be convenient to introduce here the notion of "Tate twist". The action of $G_n$ on $\mu_{p^n}$ defines the so called cyclotomic character $\kappa_n : G_n \to \mu_{p^n}$. By Pontryagin duality, $<a>_n\cong Hom (H_n, \mathbf Z/p^n)$, but this is *not* an isomorphism of $G_n$-modules because $G_n$ acts trivially on $\mathbf Z/p^n$, and via $\kappa$ on $\mu_{p^n}$. All calculations done, the natural action of $G_n$ on $<a>_n$ is via $(\kappa_n)^{-1}.(\chi_n)^{-1}$. But $a\in K^*$, so that $\chi_n =(\kappa_n)^{-1}$. Coming back to our normality condition, we thus conclude that it is equivalent to $a$ mod ${{K_n}^*}^{p^n}$ being an eigenvector for the eigencharacter $(\kappa_n)^{-1}$. Since $a\in K^*$, this is possible only for values of $n$ s.t. $K$ contains  $\mu_{p^n}$.

Comment: Thank you . But I think  the first sentence is wrong.  Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_2, a=15$. Then $\mathbb{Q}_2(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}_2$ is Galois for every $\alpha^4=15$.  But there is no $4$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: I think the problem is not with $2$. For example, $K=\mathbb{Q}_3$, $a=10$, then $x^3-a=(x-b)(x^2+cx+d)$ in $\mathbb{Q}_3[x]$. Then  $\mathbb{Q}_3(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}_3$ is Galois for every $\alpha^3=a$. But we know  $\mu_3 \not\subset \mathbb{Q}_3$.

Comment: You are right. This seems to be fundamentally a p-adic problem. I tried something with the so called "false Tate curve", but have not yet succeeded.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I do not fully understand your answer. To me, this answer shows that given $n\geq 1$, we can choose some $a\in K$ such that $K(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/K$ is Galois. Am I right? But my question is not this style.

Comment: In the kummerian situation, I showed that , given $n\ge 1$, if  $a\in K^*$ is not in Ker $\epsilon_n$ (I index the map $\epsilon$ for clarity), then $K(\sqrt [n] a)/K$ is Galois. Note that  Ker $\epsilon_n$ is the Kummer radical of $K(\mu_{p^n})/K$, so the condition $a\notin$  Ker $\epsilon_n$ is just your condition $a$ is not a root of unity.

Comment: So it seems for me , we  need to investigate $\cap \mathrm{Ker}\epsilon_n$?  I do not work out this intersection.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot consider the intersection of the Ker $\epsilon_n$’s because $K^*/{K^*}^{p^n}$ does not map into $K^*/{K^*}^{p^{n+1}}$; in the other direction, you have only the canonical surjection $K^*/{K^*}^{p^{n+1}}\to K^*/{K^*}^{p^n}$. It's better to think of Kummer radicals, but then I realize I have been sloppy in asserting that Ker $\epsilon_n$ is the Kummer radical of $K(\mu_{p^n})/K$ since $K$ does not contain $\mu_{p^n}$ a priori. Fortunately the $G$-cohomology of the exact sequence  $1\to \mu_{p^n}\to L^* \to {L^*}^{p^n}\to 1$ gives an isomorphism...

Comment: ...Ker $\epsilon_n  \cong H^1(G,\mu_{p^n}$), in particular it's cyclic (recall that $G=Gal(L/K)$). This is all we need. The additional information on the size of $K^*/{K^*}^{p^n}$allows in any case to single out a class $a_n$ mod ${K^*}^{p^n}$ which does not belong to Ker $\epsilon_n$. So we have proved that, for all $n\ge 1$, there exists a class $a_n$ mod ${K^*}^{p^n}$ s.t. $K(\sqrt [{p^n} ]a)/K$ is galois. This contradicts the property stated in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for you interests in this question.   But I still confused :- (      You showed that for each $n$,  we can find some $a_n$ (is not a root of unity) such that $K(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/K$ is Galois. (Am I right?)      But my statement is the following: Given  a  fixed element  $a\in K$ which is not a root of unity. (I guess the following holds) Then  $K(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/K$ is 
 not Galois for sufficiently large $n$.   I think these two statements are different.

Comment: - ( You showed that for each n, we can find some an (is not a root of unity) such that K(a−−√pn)/K is Galois. (Am I right?)  * Yes

Comment: Given a fixed element a∈K which is not a root of unity. (I guess the following holds) Then K(a−−√pn)/K is not Galois for sufficiently large n. I think these two statements are different.  * You're right again. I misunderstood your hypothesis on $a$. I'll take a new look.

Comment: I gave the solution in a new EDIT.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do not understand the first sentence in the second paragraph. $L_n/K$ is always normal by their definitions, right?  However,  your answer gives me a  hint to prove my guess. The point to me now is to  prove that,  when $a$ is not a root of unity, $K(\sqrt[p^n]{a})/K$ is not abelian when $n$ sufficiently large. I think I can work out this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer sooner, I've been away for a conference. Of course $L_n/K$ is the normal closure of $K(\sqrt [p^n]a)$, but here $a\in K$ by hypothesis, so that $L_n/K$ should be abelian. You need to write down the general criterion to see that this cannot happen for all $n$. But you saw it. Actually, Gal ($L_n/K$) is a semi-direct produit, and above $K(\sqrt  [{p^n}] 1)$ (for all $n$), you get a Galois extension over $K$ usually called the "false Tate curve".  PS: Are you related to Jet Li, the star of kung fu movies ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I attend for a conference too.   I have no relation with him :-